# Highlighting Duplicate Rows in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to write a script in Google Sheets that finds duplicates between 2 columns and highlights the entire row to indicate a duplicate. Here is the trick:

- I have several columns in my sheet but am only comparing 2 of them for duplicates. Lets say column A and B.
- If a value in column A is found to be a duplicate of column B, it should highlight the entire row (or at least columns A, B, and C).
- The duplicate in column B will also need to be highlighted but only after 3 duplicates in in column A have been found. In other words, it will be highlighted for every 3 duplicates that are found.

Currently, I have a script that highlights duplicates but it only highlights the specific cell when I'd like multiple cells in the column to be highlighted. Additionally, duplicates for one of the columns are highlighted only after 3 duplicates are found.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The first part is easy:

Custom formula:

```
=$A2=$B2
```

Apply to Range:

```
A2:D13
```

Enter in A2 (Assumes a header row). Change D to last column.

The second part is a little hard to understand, but this should give you an idea. It checks column C for three duplicates and highlights the cell. Add to C2:

Custom formula:

```
=countif($C2:$C,$C2)>2
```

Apply to:

```
C2:C13
```