# Highlight row based on duplicate cell contents google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

The answer in this question [Highlighting Duplicate Rows in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274708/highlighting-duplicate-rows-in-google-sheets]) works perfectly to highlight the duplicate cells in a column. What I'm wanting to do is one step futher and highlight the rows that each of those duplicated cells are in.

So if I've got duplicated cells in column c that are highlighted, how do I also highlight the rows?

Thanks!

Here's the current formatting I have to highlight duplicates in Column C.

[Current conditional formatting equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3TBG.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Apply to range to A1:Z (change Z to last column you want to highlight). And change the Custom formula to =countif($C:C,$C1)>1. You need to use the absolute reference ($).

Comment: Countif only have one argument, the range. The formula you're describing is not correct.